# Connection made to the postgres server,but datas refuse to be fetched from table "students"of database "student"

Tags: postgresql, go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func logFatal(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

const (
    HOST     = "localhost"
    PORT     = 5432
    USER     = "Blablabla"
    PASSWORD = ""
    DBNAME   = "student"
)

type student struct {
    ID          int    `json:"id"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    Department  string `json:"department"`
    Year_Joined string `json:"year_joined"`
}

var students []student

var db *sql.DB

func main() {

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD, DBNAME)

    var err error

    db, err = sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    logFatal(err)

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected")

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/students", getStudents).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))

}

func getStudents(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var theStudent student

    students = []student{}

    rows, err := db.Query("select * from students")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("there was an error", err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&theStudent.ID, &theStudent.Name, &theStudent.Department, &theStudent.Year_Joined)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        students = append(students, theStudent)

    }

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(students)

}
```

And this is the database

```
Last login: Sat May 29 07:24:12 on ttys003
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/11/bin/psql -p5432 "student"
 ~   new-feature ●✚  /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/11/bin/psql -p5432 "student"
psql (11.2)
Type "help" for help.

student=# select * from students;
 id | name  | department | year_joined 
----+-------+------------+-------------
  1 | ola   | csc        | 1990
  2 | Kenny | math       | 2019
(2 rows)

student=#
```

And this is the result am getting from vscode terminal

```
Connected
there was an error pq: relation "students" does not exist<nil>`enter code here`
```

Comment: What happens if you do `rows, err := db.Query("select * from \"student\".\"students\"")`?

Comment: this must be some mistake with creating or allowing the table. see an example of deception here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598398/pq-relation-does-not-exist-when-running-sql-query-in-golang

Comment: @dave the response is : Connected
there was an error pq: relation "student.students" does not exist<nil>

Comment: @dave, unless there is a schema named `student` that query is not going to work.

Comment: In `psql` what does the following show?: 1) `\d students` 2) `show search_path ;`. Add the results of 1) & 2) as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver,i have just a "student" database,am still stalk in the problem.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver after i ran \dt this is result i got : student=# \dt
           List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  |   Owner    
--------+----------+-------+------------
 public | students | table | Oluwashola
(1 row)

student=#

Comment: Please add the result of `\dt` as update to your question, so others don't have to look through the comments. Also add the result of `show search_path;`.  From what I have seen so far it seems to me like you are not connecting to the database you think you are and whatever you are connecting to does not have the `students` table.

Answer (score 1):

After line by line debugging ,i realised that connection to the database worked but the problem is at the postgresql syntax,the syntax supposed to be 'select*from from table' instead of 'select * from table'.Which means it does not support space between the select and (*) and (*) from from.Thanks